# DHCP option 43 on switch Dell PowerConnect 5500

Tags: switch, dhcp, dell, wlc, powerconnect

I have Dell PowerConnect 5524.

Put

```
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 43 hex f104ac1338fa
```

got

```
Option code 43 is not a valid HEX string.
```

Strange. Its worked ok for me on Cisco device. Looking at User Guide:

> hex hex-string—Specifies dotted hexadecimal data: Each byte in
>   hexadecimal character strings is two hexadecimal digits. Bytes are
>   separated by a period or colon

Trying

```
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 
  ip-list              Specify an IP address list.
  POSITIVE INTEGER     Specify the DHCP option code number
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 43 
  ascii                ASCII.
  hex                  Specify Option type as Hexadecimal.
  ip                   Specify Option type as IP address.
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 43 hex 
  WORD                 Specify Option type as Hexadecimal.
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 43 hex f1.04.ac.13.38.fa
Option code 43 is not a valid HEX string.
SW01(config-dhcp)# option 43 hex f1:04:ac:13:38:fa
Option code 43 is not a valid HEX string.
```

Question - how do i configure option 43 on this switch?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Option 43 is usually used for an IP address to a WLC on a different VLAN or subnet than a WAP. Your hex string is longer than an IP address. Did you try it with an ASCII string, like `option 43 ascii "192.168.10.5"` or an IP address, like `option 43 ip 192.168.10.5`? Maybe the hex string needs to be surrounded by double-quotes `"`?

Comment: The fact is that cisco require strict format for their APs - first byte is F1, second is length (in my case only one address so it is 04), next four bytes is hex-digits IP address.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have difficulties towards configuring dhcp on the dell 5524 which is a layer 2 switch. A good switch in my experience, but it isn't a layer 3 switch.

You should use a layer 3 switch that provides the wanted dhcp options and/or relay the dhcp packets from your 5524 to a dedicated dhcp server (*nix dhcpd or window$ dhcp).

See this link for some more information:
http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/network-switches/f/866/t/19501905

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it's layer 2 switch. I called to DELL support and got info that the built-in DHCP server have a poor functionality and does not match RFC. So they propose me to use high-end models of their switches ;)